# Activar botón Ajustes de Aplicación en la pantalla de Datos usados de Ajustes de Android

Tags: java, android

Veo que algunas aplicaciones en la pantalla de `Datos usados` en la configuración del sistema Android, al pulsar sobre una App del listado, en su vista de `Uso de datos de la aplicación` se activa el botón `Ajustes de Aplicación` y al pulsar se abre la actividad de preferencias dentro de la App.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extraído de: [Administración del uso de red](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

> A partir de Android 4.0, la aplicación Configuración del sistema permite que los usuarios vean cuántos datos de red utilizan sus aplicaciones en primer plano y en segundo plano. Los usuarios pueden inhabilitar el uso de los datos en segundo plano para apps individuales. Para evitar que los usuarios deshabiliten el acceso de tu app a los datos en segundo plano, debes utilizar la conexión de datos de forma eficiente y permitir que los usuarios definan mejor el uso de datos de tu app a través de la configuración de tu aplicación.

Para activar el botón `Ajustes de Aplicación` de dentro de la pantalla de consumo de datos de la app en ajustes del sistema.

Se debe añadir en el **AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<activity android:name="SettingsActivity" ... >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: vamo arriba los webervices